# 2FA options for single yubikey and many hosts

Tags: multi-factor, yubikey

I'm considering using yubikey (5 NFC model) as second factor for couple of Linux hosts. I'm interested in sticking it somewhere in PAM stack, so things like `sudo` are protected. Most of those hosts are only remote, that is I can't plug they key in the remote host. I have following options:

1. use `yubico-pam` with their YubicoCloud verifying every code the key provides. Simple enough to set up and convenient to use (touch to auth) but completely useless for a host that can't talk to Yubico's servers (eg. in a private network without Internet access) and a potential problem for server that loses its network connectivity (eg. crappy uplink).
2. use `pam_oath` with HOTP-OATH configured in one of the key's slots. This does away with the dependency on the third party and maintains convince of "touch to auth". On a flip side, there's only room for one secret, so every host would have to use it - if a host is compromised, you need to reissue the secret on all hosts
3. use `pam_oath` with yubikey's OATH application. Can have multiple secrets (32?), with the downside that I now need to run `ykman oath code ...` in order to get the code. This won't work if the client is a Chromebook for example. Plus you need to copy&paste the code.

There's `mode=challenge-response` in `yubico-pam` but from what I understand, the key needs to be plugged in directly into the host where this pam stack is running in order to receive the challenge.

Is there any other method that I have missed? Have I missed anything in terms of upsides/downsides and limitations? With just a handful of hosts I'm partial to the second method, but I wonder what are people using for large deployments and large number of hosts?

Thanks!